# Loop a SQL query in R

Tags: sql, r

I'm hoping to find a unique address identifier from a SQL table. The table on SQL server is too large for me to pull it into R. I have the connection set up, but I don't know how to query each row of the table that I have in R according to each column.

So I have one table loaded into R that has postcode, street, house number etc.

In SQL I have the same table, but with a unique identifier that is missing from what I have in R.

How can I pull just the unique identifiers into my table in R?

Below is one line of how it looks on SQL Server, in R I have the same table **but without the UDPRN code**. How can I get UDPRN into my R data for each row?

| UDPRN | BUILDING_NUMBER | THROUGHFARE | POST_TOWN | POSTCODE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 59 | LONG ROAD | LONDON | N1 2GT |

Comment: Can you provide us some example data and show what you have tried so far? For example, how would you do it if the R table only contained a single row?

Comment: Hey, I have added a line of data as an example. I am a bit stumped for where to start, I'd usually just pull into R and marge the two with the relevant join. But, not sure how to make it work with just a connection to the SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

My apologize,R should:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(RMariaDB)
library(DBI)

conn <- dbConnect(RMariaDB::MariaDB(), 
                  host = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
                  port = 3306,
                  user = 'xxxxxx',
                  password = 'xxxxxx',
                  dbname = 'high_school')
dbListTables(conn)

res <- dbSendQuery(conn, "SELECT * FROM exam WHERE stud_id = 21")

dbDisconnect(conn)
```

Comment: But what if you have many observations for stud_id? i.e. stud_id = c(1, 2, 3, ..., n)

And then you want to do this based upon two characteristics? For instance if stud_id had duplicates, but these duplicates were males and females being assigned the same stud_id, so a match for male or female is also required.

Comment: In my database, stud_id is a primary key so it is unique. By the case you mentioned, you could try to change "WHERE stud_id =21 & gender = 'male'" in SQL Query

Comment: What if you have a list of students and you want to check them all at once? So many values of stud_id

Comment: for (studid in c(21,33,5,8)){
      query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM exam WHERE stud_id = %2d", studid)
      res <- dbGetQuery(conn, query)
      print(res)
    }